# How do I use logrotate to remove old log tarballs?

Tags: tar, archive, rm, logs, logrotate

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.  I want to rotate log files daily, including deleting old tarballs.  I edited my logrotate.conf file, /etc/logrotate.conf, like so

```
/home/rails/myproject/log {
        daily
        rotate 4
        compress
        delaycompress
        missingok
        notifempty
        create 644 root root
}
```

This has been like this for quite some time (a few months at least), but I still see tarballs from December

```
myuser@myproject:~$ ls -al /home/rails/myproject/log/
total 8621332
drwxr-xr-x  2 rails rails       4096 Apr 10 19:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 rails rails       4096 Apr 10 10:18 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 rails rails          0 Nov  1 16:33 development.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 rails rails          0 Oct 22 15:12 .keep
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails 8583649390 Apr 10 19:09 production.log
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails    4213027 Dec 31 06:55 production.log.1
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails     887381 Dec 13 06:29 production.log.10.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails     639810 Dec 12 06:41 production.log.11.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails    1034755 Dec 11 06:41 production.log.12.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails     824498 Dec 10 06:28 production.log.13.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails     686155 Dec  9 06:53 production.log.14.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails     634700 Dec  8 06:42 production.log.15.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails       4277 Dec  7 06:35 production.log.16.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails   33388963 Dec  6 06:50 production.log.17.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails   42522255 Dec  5 06:44 production.log.18.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails   25831496 Dec  4 06:25 production.log.19.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails     184096 Dec  3 06:45 production.log.20.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails     313414 Dec  2 06:31 production.log.21.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails     306576 Dec  1 06:42 production.log.22.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails     441101 Nov 30 06:40 production.log.23.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails     264538 Nov 29 06:27 production.log.24.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails    1121126 Nov 28 06:31 production.log.25.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails   13990139 Nov 27 06:35 production.log.26.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails   34321217 Nov 26 06:38 production.log.27.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails   10963566 Nov 25 06:53 production.log.28.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails   69216879 Nov 24 06:29 production.log.29.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails       2340 Dec 30 06:30 production.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails       2624 Dec 29 06:38 production.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails       6354 Dec 28 06:46 production.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails    1113173 Dec 27 06:41 production.log.5.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails     163933 Dec 16 06:30 production.log.7.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails     309826 Dec 15 06:51 production.log.8.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails    1070471 Dec 14 06:53 production.log.9.gz
```

Is there another option I need to add that will cause the older tarballs to be deleted?  I'm happy if files older than 7 days are removed from the file system.

Comment: As I know `rotate 4` should do the work, man page says: log files are rotated count times before being removed. remove the old ones your config will do the rest.

Comment: When you say " remove the old ones your config will do the rest", do you mean I need to manually delete old files?  I would like to configure the logrotate program so that it does it for me.  That's a pain to have to periodically login every few days and manually delete files.

Comment: I meant for first time, after that it will only keep 4 copy of them. maybe there is a config to do this but I'm not aware of that.

Comment: THis config has been like this for a while -- a couple of months at least.  I'm pretty sure the logrotate program got these files into the .tar.gz form, but I'm not sure why it didn't delete them.  Do you know?

Comment: Run:  `sudo logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf`, check the result.

Comment: Interestingly, the rotated logs are owned by rails, but your logrotate configuration doesn't mention user/groups at all, so they should have been owned by root.